# How to change character-set-client and collation-connection from latin1 to utf8 in Mysql trigger

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8

We work in MySQL 5.6.30-76.3-log. MySQL system variables have utf8 set:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%' :
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value           |
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8            |
| character_set_connection | utf8            |
| character_set_database   | utf8            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary          |
| character_set_results    | utf8            |
| character_set_server     | utf8            |
| character_set_system     | utf8            |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

But when creating trigger from Python 2.7.6 script I see another character-set for this trigger: 
character_set_client latin1
collation_connection  latin1_swedish_ci
database_collation  utf8_unicode_ci

Please advice how to change character_set_client, collation_connection to utf8 in trigger definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASS,
             db=DB_NAME, charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
```

Other python notes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: Thanks! It helped.